# How to add a new container to my layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, page-layouts

I am trying to add a new container for configurable options in my layout and call the child theme from a custom view.

Here is the part of the code from my view.phtml :

```
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
 <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Nothing special as it is a default part of magento.

Now looking at the layout we see the following default as well :

```
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container1" as="container1">
    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container1</value></action>
    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
<block type="core/template_facade" name="product.info.container2" as="container2">
    <action method="setDataByKey"><key>alias_in_layout</key><value>container2</value></action>
    <action method="setDataByKeyFromRegistry"><key>options_container</key><key_in_registry>product</key_in_registry></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper</block></action>
    <action method="append"><block>product.info.options.wrapper.bottom</block></action>
</block>
```

and a bit lower for the configurable product :

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable translate="label" module="catalog">
<label>Catalog Product View (Configurable)</label>
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.configurable" as="product_type_data" template="catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.configurable.extra" as="product_type_data_extra" translate="label">
            <label>Product Extra Info</label>
        </block>
    </block>
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.availability" as="product_type_availability" template="catalog/product/view/type/availability/default.phtml" />
</reference>
<reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_type_configurable" name="product.info.options.configurable" as="options_configurable" before="-" template="catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml">
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.renderers" as="attr_renderers" />
        <block type="core/text_list" name="product.info.options.configurable.after" as="after" />
    </block>
</reference>
```

So, what I am trying to do is to create another container product.info.options.wrapper with a different template. So that I could call from my view page $this->getChildChildHtml('container3', '', true, true) or $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) when needed.

Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Thanks a lot (I think my approach is wrong, what I want is to have different option template for different view template)